# Comparar un String con un Array

Tags: java, array, string, poo, comparaciones

Lo primero disculpas por que quizás lo que quiero hacer no es ni apropiado. Acabo de comenzar a aprender en JAVA y estoy realizando ejercicios por mi cuenta.

La pregunta es la siguiente: ¿ puedo comparar en un while un string que toma por una entrada de scanner con un Array? Por una parte veo que sí pues al aplicar este código me funciona correctamente pero solo para la posición que yo le ordene(en este caso la 0).

¿cómo puedo declarar que compare todas las posiciones que hay en el array? Igual esto no tiene mucho sentido. Pero agradezco vuestra colaboración.

```
public void elige_primero(String primer_plato){


        while(primer_plato.equals(primeros[0])==false){ 
            System.out.println("Primer plato mal introducido vuelve a intentarlo lo siento: ");
            primer_plato=entrada.nextLine();

        }
        if(primer_plato.equals(primeros[0])==true){
            System.out.println("plato correcto.");
            this.primer_plato=primer_plato;

        }
    }
```

Bien quiero que el "primer plato introducido " lo compare con el array y  si existe uno de esas cadenas de caracteres dentro, lo almacene. ¿Qué sería lo correcto?

No sé si me he explicado bien. Disculpas de nuevo. Gracias.

Comment: No entendí bien tu pregunta, quieres que si el plato ya existe en el array, lo guarde aunque esté repetido?

Comment: Para recorrer un array debes de utilizar el bucle for, no el while. Deberías de indicar que necesitas hacer para tener una mejor idea.

Comment: @DanielMontes El programa pregunta que primero elige dentro de un array que se llama primeros y lo almacena en un string llamado primer_plato. Cuando le pide que primero quiere elegir, quiero que verifique si eso que ha escrito se encuentra en el array y si esta mal que le haga repetir. Gracias.

Comment: @Youshiro Dispongo de un array  llamado primeros que contiene 3 platos y un metodo que pregunta al cliente cual de los primeros elige, este es almacenado en un string. Quiero que compare lo escrito por scanner con el array y si es correcto almacenarlo en el string y si no que vuelva a escribirlo. No sé si me he explicado mejor ahora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución, sería crear un método que sólo validara si el plato es correcto y un `while` que repitiera la entrada hasta que se introduzca una correcta, por ejemplo:

```
  static String[] primeros = {"Sopa", "Pasta", "Ensalada"};

  public boolean esUnPrimeroCorrecto(String primerPlatoElegido) {
    for(String primero: primeros) {
      if (primero.equalsIgnoreCase(primerPlatoElegido)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public void elige_primero() {
    String primer_plato = entrada.nextLine();
    while(!esUnPrimeroCorrecto(primer_plato)) {
      System.out.println("Primer plato mal introducido vuelve a intentarlo lo siento: ");
      primer_plato=entrada.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("plato correcto.");
    this.primer_plato=primer_plato;
  }
```

Comment: funciona correctamente, por lo que veo el método boolean recibe un string que entiendo que recoge por teclado (aunque me cuesta entenderlo también). Pero no consigo verlo correctamente la comunicación entre los dos métodos. No obstante acabo de empezar en esto. Continuaré estudiándolo.

Comment: El método en ese código recibe la variable `primer_plato` la cual es la que almacena el valor que introduce el usuario. El valor va cambiando cada vez que se comprueba y resulta que es erroneo.